# for loop not executing any instructions outside of loop

Tags: c, gcc, for-loop

For reference, I'm copying this example (nearly) letter for letter from page 18 in [*The C Programming Language, Second Edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*count characters in input, 2nd version*/
main(){
    double n;
    for (n = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++n)
        ;
    printf("%.0f\n", n); /*this never prints*/
}
```

I wasn't sure if it was my version of gcc (I'm a noob):

```
% gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Because

```
for (n = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++n)
    printf("%.0f",n); /*returns 0123456...n*/
```

I tried printing "foo" instead of value n, just to see. It still isn't printing.

What am I missing here? I don't like moving ahead while ignoring little problems like these.

=====================================

## EDIT

So the end result should be:

```
% gcc ./counter.c -o ./counter
% ./counter
foo
3
```

Right now, this is the output from the first snippet:

```
% ./counter
foo
0123
```

And the second one:

```
% ./counter
foo

^C
%
```

Comment: What do you expect it to be doing? It should count how many times you enter a character and then print out that number, if I'm understanding correctly

Comment: Aside from the `;` at the end of the `for` line which shouldn't be there, you do have to enter a character into the console and press the Enter key every time the `for` loop runs before the body will be executed, because `getchar` doesn't return until the user has entered a character and hit Enter.

Comment: Why are you using a `double` to count characters?  An `unsigned long` would be more than big enough (unless you're feeding your program multi-gigabyte input files).  Incidentally, you generally shouldn't include the answer in your question; that's what the (accepted) answer is for.

Comment: @Keith the file I wrote at home uses int. It also forgoes the semicolon indented on it's own line (it's after the end of the for loop line), all of which I did here for the sake of staying true to the example I cited in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on an OSX or linux box, you need to type `Ctrl+D` on its own line to generate an EOF <strike>character</strike>. On Windows,  `Ctrl+Z` on its own line. Don't type `Ctrl+Z` on a unix box because that will just send your proces to the background.

You are typing `Ctrl+C` which is break, and will send a `SIGTERM` to your program.

On my mac, I get:

```
$ ./foo
hello
6D
```

Or if you don't want to signal the EOF condition, use echo and a pipe:

```
$ echo "hello" | ./foo 
6
```

Note that the `EOF` has to be on its own line. a `^D` is printed, and then 6 overwrites the ^, so it looks like the output is `6D`.

Of course, in the two above examples, the characters being counted are `h e l l o \n`. If you don't want a newline, do this:

```
$ echo -n "hello" | ./foo 
5
```

Comment: There is no EOF character.  It's a special value used by the IO library for signaling.  This value is usually -1, which can't even be represented as a `char` if that type is unsigned.  Ctrl-D and Ctrl-Z are used to signal to the shell that you're done.

Comment: You are correct, and I've updated my answer. You still need to send an EOF signal to terminate the OP's loop without ending the process prematurely.

Comment: This is true. I didn't know ctrl+d forced an EOF. I can't get it to work any other way...though I don't like it. I'll ignore this peculiarity for now...thanks.

Comment: it isn't a peculiarity - that's how it is done. The other thing you could do is: `$ echo "hello" | ./foo"`

Comment: I see. I'll remember to adjust character counting results by one, peculiar or not.

Comment: in either case, there is a newline at the end of "hello", which is why you get six rather than five.

Comment: @Matthew: The value EOF can't be represented as an `unsigned char`.  `getchar()` returns either (a) the input character, represented as an `unsigned char` and then converted to `int`, or (b) the value `EOF`.  The `EOF` value is `getchar()`'s way of indicating an end-of-file *condition*.  (It's not a signal; that's something else.)

Comment: @Keith, I said "This value is usually -1, which can't even be represented as a char if that type is unsigned." which I think is equivalent to your point.  I'm aware of UNIX signals; I meant "signal" in the plan English sense, not the `signal.h` sense.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: I managed to miss the phrase "if that type is unsigned" -- but the fact that it can't be represented as an `unsigned char` is really what's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You shouldn't have that semi-colon after the `for`.</s>  That means the only thing in your loop is an empty statement.

Actually, David is correct.  The empty statement *is* the only thing in the loop, but that's fine.  It will count the number of characters.  Then, *outside* the loop, it will print the total.

This [demo](http://ideone.com/Ars8Q) shows that it works as intended (6-character input results in printing 6).  However, I would use braces, or keep the indentation as in the original for clarity.

Comment: The semicolon is required if you want to print only the total number of characters, not a running count. It seems like the question is saying that with the semicolon in the "usual" place (to print a running count), it works, but with the semicolon in the unusual place (to print only the total), it doesn't.

Comment: @Matthew, yes, but what happens if I print "foo" there? I'd get [n] occurrences of "foo". I'm looking for just the end result, on one line.